# Nginx and directory list doesn't work:

Tags: nginx

I have done just as in the tutorials but is simply not working:

```
server {
    location /abc {
        autoindex on;
        root          /home/user/abc/;
    }
}
```

It gives me 403 Forbidden, what I'm doing wrong?
thanks; I've tried to use a "/" at the end, and also without but no changes.

When I go to myip/abc I hope to see some directory list but no. Even if I try to go to myip/abc/myfile.txt it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by using the root instead of alias it will look in the wrong path. Also in the http the user was www-something and has had no permissions, thanks ubuntu, so now I had to change to my name and it worked:

- Alias instead of root for the right path
- Define the right user that has permissions to the folder you want